# mod_evasive: Stop attacks against wp-login.php

Tags: apache-2.2, spam, hacking, brute-force-attacks

i would like to stop attacks against some user's WordPress-installations on my server.

This is an example of an attack:

```
91.208.65.12 - - [20/Oct/2015:10:33:08 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 403 1317 "-" "-"
91.208.65.12 - - [20/Oct/2015:10:33:08 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 4114 "-" "-"
91.208.65.12 - - [20/Oct/2015:10:33:09 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 4114 "-" "-"
91.208.65.12 - - [20/Oct/2015:10:33:09 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 4114 "-" "-"
91.208.65.12 - - [20/Oct/2015:10:33:09 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 4114 "-" "-"
91.208.65.12 - - [20/Oct/2015:10:33:09 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 403 1317 "-" "-"
91.208.65.12 - - [20/Oct/2015:10:33:09 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0" 200 4114 "-" "-"
```

As you can see there is a 403-response from time to time but the attacker can continue the attacks on the next request.

This is the output of `cat /etc/apache2/conf.d/mod_evasive.conf`

```
DOSEmailNotify   myaddress@example.com

DOSHashTableSize 3097
DOSPageCount 2
DOSSiteCount 50
DOSPageInterval 5
DOSSiteInterval 1
DOSBlockingPeriod    300
DOSLogDir           "/var/log/mod_evasive"
DOSSystemCommand "sudo /usr/local/bin/ddos_system.sh %s"
```

In my log-directory there are some entries:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    6 Okt 20 10:36 dos-176.148.93.14
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    6 Okt 20 10:30 dos-176.31.49.45
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    6 Okt 20 10:31 dos-192.163.238.218
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    6 Okt 20 10:30 dos-66.135.55.206
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    6 Okt 20 10:36 dos-79.249.19.235
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    6 Okt 20 10:32 dos-85.93.30.190
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    6 Mai  2 22:02 dos-85.93.3.55
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    6 Okt 20 10:33 dos-89.40.221.197
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    6 Okt 20 10:30 dos-91.208.65.12
```

An example of the content of these entries:

```
cat dos-176.148.93.14
20774
```

Well, my question is: How can I block these attackers for a longer time and how can I improve my mod_evasive configuration?

Comment: Try using fail2ban instead.

Comment: Hi, the problem is, that I have to monitor xmlrpc.php, too. And xmlrpc.php returns 200 instead of 403 or 401 and some mobile apps for remote-access to wp use xmlrpc.php and get banned very often.